# Jax-rs annotation Path is not work in java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs

I have spring boot application with starter version 2.1.16, and spring-boot-starter-web dependency. So, i want use javax.ws.rs-api library, and add dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

So when i create controller, and add @Path, @Get - i don't get answer from the server (404 not found). How makes it work?

```
package com.example.test;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    //Doesn't work (404 not found
    @GET
    @Path("/my_test")
    public String check() {
        return "hi!";
    }

    //Work
    @RequestMapping("/my_test2")
    public String check2() {
        return "hi2!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? Spring has its own mechanism for handling REST calls, so if you want to use a different technology altogether (like JAX-RS) you need to use a JAX-RS _implementation_ rather than just the API (= just the annotations and a few helper classes)

Comment: EIther use JAX-RS or use Spring MVC, mixing both in 1 class will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

if you use spring boot starter version 2.1.16, you will normally have a parent pom which will also define the default version for the above dependency.

Then replace `@RestController` with `@Path("/")` from package `javax.ws.rs.Path`

Now it should be working.

Keep in mind your embedded server now, will be `jersey` instead of default `tomcat`.

Edit: Also as found from the author of the question another change is needed to register a `ResourceConfig`. This is also described here in the [official documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.16.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jersey)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the post above, you need to add the config class:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourceConfig resourceConfig(MyController myController) {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(myController);
        return config;
    }
}
```